# How do I search for a certain item in multiple models django?

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and I am trying to build web site for my friend how makes handmade lamps.
My problem is that I have 3 different models that contains different types of lamps, and I want to get access to certain picture in any of this 3 models and display a picture and description on the other page,but it shows only some pictures from first model and for others throws an error.

this is my html and views.py codes.

```html
{% for q in project1.reverse|slice:":2"%}
        <div class="image-selected__lamps">
            <a href="{% url 'project_detail' q.pk%}">
                <img src="{{q.image.url }}">
            </a>

        </div>
        {%endfor%}
        {% for e in project2.reverse|slice:":2"%}
        <div class="image-selected__lamps">
            <a href="{% url 'project_detail' e.pk  %}">
            <img src="{{e.image.url}}">
            </a>
        </div>           
       {%endfor%}
        {% for s in project3.reverse|slice:":2"%}
        <div class="image-selected__lamps">
            <a href="{% url 'project_detail' s.pk %}">
            <img src="{{s.image.url}}">
            </a>
        </div>          
        {%endfor%}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y29lo.png)

```
def project_detail(request, pk):
    project = (LampType1.objects.get(pk=pk), LampType2.objects.get(pk=pk), LampType3.objects.get(pk=pk))

    context = {
        'project': project,
    }
    return render(request, 'project_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: show how the model of one of the classes looks so I can explain how you can use the image.

Comment: class LampType1(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = ImageField(upload_to='media')

Answer (score 0):

Edward this might be happening because you are passing the same id/pk to all the models and you got a picture from the first model and not from the other because an object with that id/pk does not exit in the other models.

To check, register your models in the admin and check weather an object with that particular id exit or not.

Comment: I already registered them, and I didn't catch the second part.
I am just trying to figure out the way to do this,I of course can just create 3 different functions for each model and 3 templates but this is not very cool thing to do.

Comment: (LampType1.objects.get(pk=pk), LampType2.objects.get(pk=pk), LampType3.objects.get(pk=pk)), in this code, you are getting lamps of all types with the same id = pk. what I said was to check whether that particular id exit in all types of lamp models or not. and also you don't have to make 3 templates you can pass your 3 
different functions to the same template (means you can have multiple variables in context)

Comment: Do you mean assign each model to a different variable and after put them all in context dictionary?I tried this and for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: Then you might be having some other issues because assigning each model to different variables and put them in context does not throw any error

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't show anything on web page.

Answer (score 0):

check if these steps have been done

**model**

```
  class LampType1(models.Model):
          title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
          description = models.TextField()  
          image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media') 
          #not
          #image = ImageField(upload_to='media')
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import setting

urlpatterns = [.....
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
from django.contrib import admin
```

**html**

```
 {% for p in project %}

    <img src="{{ p.image.url }}">
 
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes.
If i put it like this
def project_detail(request, pk):
    project = (LampType1.objects.get(pk=pk))

    context = {
        'project': project,
    }
    return render(request, 'project_detail.html', context)

it shows particular picture from first model,I just wondering if I can somehow put all 3 models in 1 function and explicitly display particular picture to user.